# Spark importing split JSON payload

Tags: json, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json structure which contains some top-level metadata and a payload which is equivalent to what pandas would define as a split orientation json payload. This was done to reduce duplication as we ingest a lot of these files.

Usually in pandas I would load the json file and pass the required parts (index, column names and data) to a DataFrame constructor, which would give me a flat table which is easy to work with and can then be exported to influxdb or sql.

```py
obj = load_json('file.json')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=obj['payload']['Time'], columns=obj['Names']['Time'], data=obj['payload']['Data'])
df['Machine_ID'] = obj['Machine_ID']
df['TimeSend'] = obj['TimeSend']
df['Version'] = obj['Version']
```

It seems that this schema is not easy to flatten with spark, as the data isn't record based and so the column names and data aren't associated. Is there anyway I can process this to flat schema with spark or should I add an extra pandas processing step in my pipeline.

```
root
 |-- Machine_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TimeSend: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Version: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Payload: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- Names: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- Time: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Edit: I found a way that works, however I'm curious whether the ordering can be relied on, because I split the dataframe before adding id's.
Probably its better to zip `Time` and `Data` to enable them both to be exploded, and work from there.

```
# Make flattened dataframe
df_ = df.select(col('Payload.Time').alias('Time'), col('Payload.Names').alias('Names'), col('Payload.Data').alias('Data'), col('Machine_ID'), col('TimeSend'), col('Version'))

# Make exploded `Data` table
columns = df_.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.Names).collect()
df_a = df_.select(explode(col('Data')))
df_a = df_a.select([df_a.col[x] for x in range(len(columns))])
df_a = rdd_data.toDF(columns)
df_a = df_a.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

# Make exploded `Metadata` table
df_b = df_.select(explode(col('Time')), col('Machine_ID'), col('TimeSend'), col('Version'))
df_b = df_b.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

# Join tables
df_c = df_a.join(df_b, "id")

# Schema is now flattened and joined
df_c.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- Machine_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TimeSend: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Version: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Index: string (nullable = true) <- From Payload.Time
 |-- TagA: double (nullable = true)  <- From Payload.Names & Data
 |-- TagB: double (nullable = true)  <- || -
 |-- TagC: double (nullable = true)  <- || -
 |-- TagD: double (nullable = true)  <- || -
```

Comment: spark.read.json(filepathandanme) . just read the columns like Payload.data if the data is array type use explode function to flattern.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you read the question. Data is ArrayType(ArrayType)DoubleType)) it only contains the values not the column names. Names is ArrayType(StringType) and contains the Column Names. It's much not as trivial as just exploding, since they must be both exploded, then split and further exploded.